# Tailwind autocompletion not working with Intellij Idea Ultimate - ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, tailwind-css

Using: Intellij Idea Ultimate - React Project

This is so simple, but I couldn't find a solution for it.
Tailwind autocompletion does work without Curly brackets.
But after adding the curly brackets, which I have to do. Tailwind autocompletion stop working.

Check the below picture.
[image]

Is there any fix for this? thx

Answer (score 2):

the issue is tracked at [WEB-49599](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49599), please follow it for updates

Comment: Great, Lena any expectations as to how much time this might take?